# Reduction to some physical interpretation of this formula

Tags: algorithms, discrete-geometry, combinatorial-optimization

**Problem** Given N 3-dimensional points which are {$p_1,p_2,..,p_n$} where $p_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i) $ . I have to find the value of the formula

$$ \sum \limits_{i=0}^n \sum \limits_{j=i+1}^n \frac{ \mid \alpha*(x_i-x_j+\beta*(y_i-y_j)+\gamma*(z_i-z_j)+\delta) \mid }{ \sqrt{ (x_i-x_j)^4+(y_i-y_j)^4+(z_i-z_j)^4} } $$

for some given $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta $.
all numbers are between 1 and M ( = 100).

I need an efficient method for the reduction of this formula to something which is easy to calculate.

So far, I have recognized that the above expression is the normal component of vector joining i and j from the the plane formed by  $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta $ divided by the square of the distance between i and j in  $l_4$ norm.

Please give any idea about how to reduce it to simpler standard form which  can be calculated efficiently.

**EDIT:** By transforming and rotating the coordinate system such that the plane formed by $\alpha , \beta ,\gamma$ and $ \delta $ is represented by $z=0$, problem reduces to finding

$$ \sum \limits_{i=0}^n \sum \limits_{j=i+1}^n \frac{ \mid z_i-z_j \mid }{ \sqrt{ (x_i-x_j)^4+(y_i-y_j)^4+(z_i-z_j)^4} } $$

Comment: Are you sure it is $4$ in exponent in denominator?

Comment: Where does this problem come from, and why do you expect a "simpler standard form" to exist?

Comment: @Arul, yes it is 4.

Comment: @StefanKohl, I need to compute the expression but for large n, brute force method is very efficient, so I asked you guys to suggest some modifications to the expression to calculate it efficiently.

Comment: @yejc I think Stefan Kohl is wondering if these expressions have a meaning?

Comment: @Arul, I have only this information.

Comment: Is this the same question as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217713/how-to-evaluate-the-following-sum ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Up to division by 2 and replacing some latin letters with greek analogues.

Comment: @yejc "Is this a homework question?" is what Stephan is trying to say.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, I am not asking anyone to solve it straight forward for me, I am just asking how to think in the right direction (at least give any keyword of the method to solve it and I 'll find the solution by myself then) . And who the hell give such a tough question for homework ? I am struggling for last 5 days still don't have any hint to solve it better than O(n^2).

Comment: you will need to evaluate $n^2/2$ terms, there is no miracle that will give you the value of this sum if you evaluate fewer terms

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, That's why I am asking this question in the first place. May be there is some interpretation of this formula using geometry or algebra which can reduce the complexity? O(n^2) is the brute force but can you prove that we cannot do better than that?

Comment: @yejc so in what context did this problem arise? That can be helpful for answerers, and also motivating if they know something about the background (Five days? You were lucky! www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe1a1wHxTyo)